# Internal CSS affected not working properly

Tags: css

I am using Internal (not inline) CSS class to format my aspx (.net) page, all things are going well except font-size. It shows some default font-size for that specific page. I had separate that page from other pages root is same but image folder is different and CSS is internal and I had checked properly with IE "Developer Tool" no confliction is there. please help me out of this.
I'd attached snapshot of problematic area.

[image]

Comment: You probably have a different font value somewhere else that is overriding that 2px.

Answer (score 0):

Is it assigned via CSS? if so, have a look here at the !important declaration, this should resolve your problem

http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your body's font is set to 2px, but this can be overridden by other classes and styles. Look at the element that is not 2px and check which style is applied. Probably this is a h2 which has a default size or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

your css styling may overridden with another style. may be it is causing this problem.